# How to UPDATE just part of a text entry in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, text, sql-update

I have a column in my database that has the absolute URLs to images.
I've just transferred the entire website to another folder so the URLs of the images have changed. So for eg. if the URL of an image in the image_URL column was like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/images/myimage.jpg
```

I need to update it like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/newfolder/images/myimage.jpg
```

The `type` for the `image_URL` column is `TEXT`. But I need to update it ONLY if the URL being used is "mysite" and not "externalsite".

What's the right SQL to use? I'm very familiar with SQL `UDATE` commands but not where I need to update only PART of a column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE table SET image = REPLACE(image, "http://www.mysite.com/images/", "http://www.mysite.com/newfolder/images/")

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just do a LIKE search for 'mysite' to get all the URL's. Then one by one, change the text and resave it to your dB.

lee

Comment: "Just do X!" is a strange answer for a question that reads "How can I do X?"

Comment: Not really. He was asking how to do X, and I explained how to do it by doing Y and Z. ;)